# Qt - Is there a way to emit a signal when a particular key is typed?

Tags: c++, qt, signals, qt-signals

I am working on a project in Qt 4.7 where a have a `QListWidget` which needs to perform a certain function when an item from the list is selected. The particular function isn't important here, so for this example let's say it is to print the value to `std::cout`. I have it right now so that it does this when a value is double-clicked, like so:

`connect(ui->myList, SIGNAL(doubleClicked(QModelIndex)),
        this, SLOT(printChoice(QModelIndex)));
...
void MyClass::printChoice(QModelIndex index)
{
  std::cout << ui->myList->model()->data(index).toString();
}`

This code works perfectly. However, my project lead said they would like it to enter this slot for whatever row of the list is currently selected when the user clicked the <kbd>F2</kbd> key. I do not know of any signals that are emitted for these keys, and looking around the web hasn't helped much. Does anyone know of a way to do this? Thanks!

EDIT: I've found that hitting <kbd>F2</kbd> while a value is selected automatically puts that row into edit mode (it must be built in to Qt) but I still need to know how to trigger a slot when that occurs.

EDIT 2: I'm getting closer. I found I could make a slot in `MyClass` called `keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)` that will register whenever certain keys are hit, including the fX keys. However, I still cannot find a way to differentiate which key triggered it, and how to make sure it was <kbd>F2</kbd>

Comment: Consider using `QShortcut`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement the virtual function `keyPressEvent` from base class `QWidget`:

```
void YourWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if( event->key() == Qt::Key_F2 )
    {
        emit F2isPressed(/* some signature */); // connected elsewhere
    }
}
```

OP Note: While this answer doesn't quite work correctly for the particular case I was trying to figure out (the <kbd>F2</kbd> key being pressed), it *does* work for pretty much any *other* key that will trigger that function (e.g the other Fx keys, etc.). It turns out <kbd>F2</kbd> is a really weird case for Qt and requires some workaround to get to work. To see how the original post was solved by myself and the poster of this question, you can look in the chat [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50902/discussion-between-tay2510-and-thnkwthprtls). I'm going to mark this answer as accepted, because although it doesn't work for this one particular case, it is in general the correct answer for this type of problem.

Comment: What's up? Any problem?

Comment: I tried this, and I'm getting strange results. It seems to work for *most* keys; if I use for example, `event->key() == Qt::Key_F3` and then hit F3, it works. However, it seems that, for F2, this doesn't work on the first button press. If a row is currently selected and I hit F2 with the code as above, it puts the selected row in edit mode *without* triggering the slot the first time, then if I click F2 again without changing the currently selected row, it works the second time. Do you happen to have any idea why this may be?

Comment: I guess there is some intervention from the built-in function of F2 (like you said in the original post). Must be disconnected (or reimplemented )if you want to customize F2's functionality.

Comment: Would you happen to have any idea where I could find this to know what to disconnect? Just about the only reference to this I can find is in the Qt Forum where someone says to look here (http://trolltech.com/developer/notes/changes/changes-3.3.8/) for a fix... but the link doesn't work :(

Comment: Hmm.. I am interested too and still finding the answer. If you happen to find it (faster than me), answer your own question, I'll vote it up.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `QShortcut` to invoke a slot :

```
QShortcut * shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_F2),this,SLOT(printChoice()));
shortcut->setAutoRepeat(false);
```

In the slot `printChoice()` you can print the contents of the selected row.